# WP eCommerce Issue in viewing product item in product page, while adding product

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Just updated **WP eCommerce** plugin to version 3.11.3. When I add a product it appear on my front page. When publishing the product, it doesn't shows on the main product page. For eg. This is a product I added, but is not visible:
http://192.168.1.104/new_word/products-page/

site url: http://192.168.1.104/new_word/

You can see the product on the new home page, but not on the main product page.

Can anyone please help me.

wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/

Comment: Why are you using **WP eCommerce** for e-commerce purpose with wordpress? Why you don't use WooCommerce instead? Woocommerce is easier, much more expandable and run in most of Wordpress e-commerce web sites…

Comment: I am using it for creating online shopping site..

Comment: my problem is solved by using WooCommerce plugin...Thank you so much for you support.